# How do I get the value of Markup::$string?

Tags: 9

I have the following code in a custom submit handler:

```
$status = \Drupal::messenger()->messagesByType('status');
foreach ($status as $delta) {
   // Here I want to extract the text string that is in $delta.
}
```

The variable `$delta` now contains this:

```
delta => stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Render\Markup
    [string:protected] => Article request My article has been created.
)
```

How do I get the protected string from `$delta`?

I've already tried some methods, but so far I haven't found one that works.

Here are those tried so far:

> Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::getMessages()
> Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::toString()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A protected variable is only accessible from the class itself. Your only option to access it from outside the class is via a public method.

Looking at the [Markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Markup.php/class/Markup/9.3.x) class, the only public methods are:

1. `count()`
2. `jsonSerialize()`
3. `__toString()`

Simply put, because Markup implements the magic method [`__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) (which returns `$this->string`), you can get that string simply by using the object as a string, e.g. `echo $my_markup_object;`

Comment: Thanks! didn't know about the PHP magic methods.